# Entity Framework ExecuteSqlCommand Missing Input Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having an issue with the ExecuteSqlCommand() method in Entity Framework (EF). I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
EXEC SomeSchema.SomeTableInsert
@Id = 1, 
@SomeData = 'This is some random data', 
@UserId = 500
```

and it works without any issues. When I try to use EF's ExecuteSqlCommand() method, I get the following error:

```
Procedure or function 'SomeTableInsert' expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied.
```

Here is the C# code:

```
var sql = "SomeSchema.SomeTableInsert @Id, @SomeData, @UserId";
var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter> 
{ 
    new SqlParameter("@Id", 1),
    new SqlParameter("@SomeData", "This is some random data"), 
    new SqlParameter("@UserId", 500)
};

dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, sqlParameters.ToArray<object>());
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. The UserId parameter is not missing and it has a valid value. Any ideas?

Update:

Here is the SQL that is run on SQL Server:

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'SomeSchema.SomeTableInsert @Id, @SomeData, @UserId',
    N'@Id int,@SomeData nvarchar(5),@UserId int',
    @Id=1,
    @SomeData='This is some random data',
    @UserId=500
```

Comment: Does it work if youwrite it like `ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, new SqlParameter("@Id", 1),
    new SqlParameter("@SomeData", "This is some random data"), 
    new SqlParameter("@UserId", 500);` ?

Comment: I tried that and it's still failing. I believe it's something with the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sql = "SomeSchema.SomeTableInsert @Id, @SomeData, @UserId";
var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter> 
{ 
    new SqlParameter("Id", 1),
    new SqlParameter("SomeData", "This is some random data"), 
    new SqlParameter("UserId", 500)
};

dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, sqlParameters.ToArray<object>());
```

Remove the @ prefix from within the SqlParameter.

Comment: This isn't making any difference. See my edit for the generated SQL.

Comment: Did you remove the @prefix. Your generated SQL still shows it.